# jQuery uniform add option to select

Tags: jquery

Im trying to add an option to a `select` element with:

```
$("select, .check, .check :checkbox, input:radio, input:file").uniform();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "loadSoundLib.php",
        success: function(msg) {
            var lines = msg.split('\n');
            $.each(lines, function(){
                if(this != "") {
                    alert(this);
                    $('#selectNewMessageSound').append('<option value="1_1.wav">Standard</option>');
                }
            });

            $.uniform.update("#selectNewMessageSound");
        }
    }); // Ajax Call
```

This is the html I try to append to:

```
<select name="select2" class="select" id="selectNewMessageSound">
</select>
```

Strange thing is my select is completely empty.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you comment out the Uniform calls? I ask because your JS looks good to me and I see the alert so you would know if the line was blank.

Comment: What happens when you log out msg? Is it spitting stuff back to you?